# Graphql, return result only if record not null

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Totally new in Gatsby (my app is build in here). Also new in Graphql but I go this project from a colleague and now I need to find a way to sort it out.

I have a query in graphql that looks as follow:

```
query MediasQuery {
    allStrapiMedias(sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          description
          date(formatString: "Do MMMM, YYYY")
          link
          poster {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                src
              }
            }
          }
          file {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue I am facing is that the `file` record can exist or not, to be more accurate, if `link` record is empty, then I should find a `file` (this is how it's been build in Strapi).

If I have at least one record with `file` then the query run normally, but as soon as I deleted this record from database all the app crash.

How can I make that query to only return `file` if `url` is empty or null?

Answer (score 0):

You are querying an object that will have one property (`file`) filled or not with an `url`. You just need to add that logic to your JavaScript and React code. When you will print the file, add the new logic, something like:

```
if (data.allStrapiMedias.edges.node.file) return <ComponentA/>
else return <ComponentB/>
```

I think that what you are looking for is something that the previous snippet. However, answering your question, you achieve it by adding filters to your query:

```
query MediasQuery {
    allStrapiMedias(
      sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }
      filter: { file: {url: {ne: null }}}
      ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          description
          date(formatString: "Do MMMM, YYYY")
          link
          poster {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                src
              }
            }
          }
          file {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

More details in [GraphQL Query Options Reference](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/).

Comment: mate, it say ne not defined

Comment: I missed the `url` in the query filter, it's updated. However, you are able to test it in the `localhost:8000/___grahpql` playground to adapt my solution (the second one). It's not about copy/pasting.